# Checkbox e PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Olá, pessoal!

Não estou conseguindo enviar valores do checkbox através do PHPMailer. Alguém poderia me dar uma dica?

```
$precisa = implode(",", $_POST['precisa[]'] );

<label>
                    <p style="margin-right: 40px;">O QUE VOCÊ PRECISA?</p>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="precisa[]" value="Site"><font color="#ffe200">Site</font>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="precisa[]" value="App"><font color="#ffe200">App</font>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="precisa[]" value="Logomarca"><font color="#ffe200">Logomarca</font><br />
                        <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="precisa[]" value="Catálogo"><font color="#ffe200">Catálogo de produtos</font><br />

                        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Enviar contato" />
                    </label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando um campo do seu form é um array (o atributo `name` precisa de conchetes), ao receber ele no php não é necessário utilizar conchetes no nome.

Mude:

```
$precisa = implode(",", $_POST['precisa[]'] );
```

para:

```
$precisa = implode(",", $_POST['precisa'] );
```

[Exemplo - phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8u7p-2mfi)

Comment: e  quando o checkbox tem names diferentes como poderia fazer?

Comment: @allanaraujo como assim?

Comment: esse é minha pergunta teria como responder ela ? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178790/como-enviar-checkbox-com-names-diferentes-para-o-mysql

Comment: tenho uma tela de pedido com um input  text e dois checkbox com names diferentes e outros dois input text para colocar a quantidades , e também com names diferentes para enviar eles para o mysql ,mas eu não sei como usar mais de um implode para inserir no banco de dados .