# Enviar dados de Checkbox por PHPMAILER

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário, e tive que incluir um campos em **checkbox**, como faço para enviar essa informações por e-mail?

HTML

```
<form class="form" method="post">       
<div class="visitenosCheckboxItem">
    <input class="css-checkbox" id="checkboxInstitucional" name="checkboxForm[]" type="checkbox">
    <label class="css-label" for="checkboxInstitucional">Institucional</label>
</div>
<div class="visitenosCheckboxItem">
    <input class="css-checkbox" id="checkboxModeloGestao" name="checkboxForm[]" type="checkbox">
    <label class="css-label" for="checkboxModeloGestao">Modelo de Gestão</label>
</div>
<div class="visitenosCheckboxItem">
    <input class="css-checkbox" id="checkboxPlanejamentoEstrategico" name="checkboxForm[]" type="checkbox">
    <label class="css-label" for="checkboxPlanejamentoEstrategico">Planejamento Estratégico</label>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn-enviar" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
```

O HTML que estou enviando vai dentro de:

```
$mail->Body = '';
```

Comment: Pode utilizar `$_POST["checkboxForm"]` para obter os valores e utilizar o [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) para enviar o e-mail. O que já tentou fazer?

Comment: Mas e como eu incluo os checkbox preenchidos para o HTML do e-mail?

Comment: Depende de como será o corpo do e-mail. O que já tentou fazer? E o que pretende fazer?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss atualizei a pergunta

Comment: relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31319/como-enviar-dados-de-checkbox-para-uma-consulta-com-mysql?rq=1

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69035/checkbox-e-phpmailer?rq=1